# Calculate Average price given year

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am trying to calculate the average price of the books in a library in a year:
public class Library

```
private List<Book> books;

private final String name;


public Library(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    books = new ArrayList<>();
}


public Library(List<Book> books, String name) {
    this.books = books;
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}



public boolean addBook(Book b) {
    return books.add(b);
}


// find average price of books in library in given year

public double calcAveragePriceInYear(int year) {
    double total = 0.0;
    for ( Book i : books) {
        if (i.getYear() == year) {
            total = total + i.getPrice();
        }

    }
    return total/ Collections.frequency(books, year);

}
```

Here is the method I am trying to create:
// find average price of books in library in given year

```
public double calcAveragePriceInYear(int year) {
        double total = 0.0;
        for ( Book i : books) {
            if (i.getYear() == year) {
                total = total + i.getPrice();
            }

        }
        return total/ Collections.frequency(books, year);

    }
```

Here is the Book Class:

```
public class Book {

    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String isbn;
    private int year;
    private double price;

    public Book(String name, String author, String isbn, int year, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
    }
```

Question is, how can I divide the total with number of times the given year is in the Library?

return total / Collections.frequency(books, year); keeps returning 0

Comment: Please see [mcve]. You have a lot of context in your question ... that actually does not matter. Always try to first establish an example (for yourself, too) that only has "your problem" in it. Meaning: A simple class with just the fields you need, and a list with hardcoded objects, so that you can easily debug the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Collections.frequency` does not make any sense here because `year` is not contained in `books` ever, it only contains `Book`s, not `int`s (`year` is an `int`).

You should simply increment a counter when you find a book with a valid year and later divide by that counter:

```
public double calcAveragePriceInYear(int year) {
    double total = 0.0;
    int numBooks = 0;
    for ( Book i : books) {
        if (i.getYear() == year) {
            total +=  i.getPrice();
            numBooks++;
        }
    }
    return total / numBooks;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do what you want by simply streaming the list of books.

- filter based on year
- get the book price for those years
- and take the average.
- the `orElse()` is a default value if no books were found for that year.

```
public double calcAveragePriceInYear(int year) {
    return books.stream().filter(bk -> bk.getYear() == year)
                .mapToDouble(Book::getPrice).average().orElse(0);
}
```